# Limit of an integral and hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, calculus-and-analysis

I want to evaluate the following integral:

```
Integrate[Sin[θ]^(D1 - Nc - 1)/(A Cos[θ] - I ϵ)^(N1 - Nc), {θ, 0, π}, 
Assumptions -> A > 0 && ϵ > 0]
```

and then take the limit $\epsilon\to0$:

```
Limit[%, ϵ -> 0]
```

However, the first integral takes eternity to produce an answer.

**Workaround I tried:**

I tried using a general variable $B$ instead of $i\epsilon$ to perform the integral. The following integral evaluates to a Gauss hypergeometric function under some conditions on the paramters:

```
Integrate[Sin[θ]^(D1 - Nc - 1)/(A Cos[θ] - B)^(N1 - Nc), {θ, 0, π}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[
>    2^(-1 + D1 - Nc) (-A - B)^(-N1 + Nc)
>      Gamma[(D1 - Nc)/2]^2 Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[(D1 - Nc)/2, 
>      N1 - Nc, D1 - Nc, (2 A)/(
>      A + B)], (Re[B/A] >= 1 || Re[B/A] <= -1 || 
>       B/A [NotElement] Reals) && Re[A + B] < 0 && Re[D1] > Re[Nc]]

Then if I take the limit $B\to 0$:

```
Limit[%, B -> 0]
```

it gives me

> ((-A)^(-N1 + Nc) Sqrt[[Pi]]
>     Gamma[(D1 - Nc)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[(D1 - Nc)/2, N1 - Nc, D1 - Nc, 
>     2])/Gamma[1/2 (1 + D1 - Nc)]

I think the above answer is the correct answer I was looking for (based on various checks with special values of $D,N_c,N_1$. But the condition $Re[A+B]<0$ means the answer may not work for the case $A>0,B=iϵ,ϵ>0$. Is there anyway to check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`AsymptoticIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticIntegrate):

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[
    Sin[θ]^(D1 - Nc - 1)/(A Cos[θ] - I ε)^(N1 - Nc),
    {θ, 0, π},
    {ε, 0, 1},
    Assumptions -> A>0 && ε>0
] /. ε->0
```

> ((-1)^-N1 ((-1)^N1 + (-1)^Nc) A^(-N1 + Nc)
>     Gamma[(D1 - Nc)/2] Gamma[1/2 (1 - N1 + Nc)])/(2 Gamma[1/2 (1 + D1 - N1)])

Comment: This is amazing!